# ServiceStack: Multiple roles share same service?

Tags: servicestack

What's the best practice if I want to create a service that is used by two different roles?  For example if you're a customer you can only get yourself, but if you are an employee you can get anybody...

Should I just create a separate service for each or inspect the session's role within the service and enforce within.

I'm trying to keep a RESTful style /customer/{CustomerId} to retrieve them.

Comment: you could go either way. two separate apis, or logic all over a single api to check `if(is_customer()) { do_customer_stuff(); } else { do_employee_version_stuff(); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a best practise, the choice to have separate services for different roles over a single service that tests for roles, should ultimately be driven by the DTOs. In ServiceStack you will have DTO request for each route, and a DTO response, so ask yourself these questions:

- Will the request DTOs be the same for both the customer and employee roles, for most of the requests? *If the answer is no, then you need separate services.*
- Will the response DTOs be the same for both the customer roles and employee roles for most the action method responses? *If the answer is no, then you need separate services.*

Essentially, if the data in and out is the same structure, and roles simply limit the number of the records the user can access then I would have one service and test for the roles from their session.

But if an employee or another role gets back significantly more fields or differently structured response data from the same route on your service API, as say a customer role, then you should be separating these services out.

Remember that your service is really just DTOs => data in and data out. The DTOs are contracts for the data that is required to be sent and received. If having multiple roles no longer means you can maintain these contracts, separate the services, otherwise stick with one.